# System solving with Substitution and Matrices

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

My class was able to produce solutions using Substitution on the following System:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+y+z=0 \\ 
2x+3y+2z=-1\\ 
x-y+z=2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
The solution was: **x = 1, y = -1, z = 0**

However, when I tried solving that system using matrices in the following format, I received a Singular Matrix Error in my calculator.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&1&0\\
      2&3&2&-1\\
1&-1&1&2
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I solved the matrix by hand, and it is true. The det = 0.

So, why are there solutions to the system using substitution, but no solutions when using matrices?

Comment: Are parameterized solutions numbers that can also fit in the solution such as: 0.5,-1,0.5?

Comment: Where did you get x = 1-t, and z = t from?

Comment: Yes that makes sense thank you :D